# How can I pass additional config options to symfony?

Tags: php, symfony

I want to pass a facebook id to my symfony application.. Where can I put that and how can i accept it ?

Comment: The symfony version  is 2.0.16

Comment: If all you want to do is pass a value in then add to parameters.ini and use $this->container->getParameter in your controllers or %parameter_name% in your service configurations.

Answer (score 0):

You can find nicely described way of doing this in this [blog post](http://richardmiller.co.uk/2011/06/01/symfony2-writing-a-dependency-injection-extension-configuration/). It might be quite a lot effort comparing to the things you want to do, but believe me, it's worth to get to know with DIC configuration.